# Old website showing instead of new one

Tags: web-development

We just migrated our website to a new host (godaddy).  I totally changed the design and layout.  I changed the website from a .NET to a wordpress website.

The website works fine on:
Linux
iPhone
Android
Over a web based internet proxy

The https version of the website does not work at all on Windows 7 or 8.  It get a Connection Reset error or a Time Out error. The http version loads the old website. I can even sign into the old website, which is weird because it should be gone.

I have tried: 
clearing the cache
different browsers
different computers and laptops in our company
different networks. I have checked it with 2 different ISPs.

There is one desktop computer running windows 8 that is showing the correct website on our company network.

How can I fix this problem?  What the heck is going on?

Comment: Was the old website actually deleted from the old host? How long has it been since you "migrated" and changed DNS? Are you only trying this within "your company" (apart from the phones you mention) - do you use a proxy?

Comment: Yes, sounds like DNS cache.

Comment: We migrated about 1 month ago.  I tested the site on a laptop with windows 8, which was connected to the user's personally wifi hotspot that they brought from home, which is a different ISP than the company's ISP.  We had the same problem.

Comment: I flushed the DNS cache with ipconfig /flushdns and still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: This is an ISP DNS cache problem.  I switched the computers to Google's public DNS and now the website is displayed properly.